# phpunit test against a specific virtual host

Tags: phpunit

I've been struggling for almost a week, but couldn't find a good solution.

I'm using laravel 4.2 and php unit 5.7.27

I'm using a custom virtual host : http://local.io

I'm using localization, and if typed in the browser it will look like this : http://local.io/en/user/signin

Here's my test function :

```
public function testViewSignin()
{
    App::setLocale('en');
    $result = $this->call('GET', '/user/signin', [], [], ['HTTP_HOST' => 'local.io']);
}
```

but when running it in the terminal `./vendor/bin/phpunit --verbose`, I always receive html code `307` and the message is `Redirecting to http://local.io/en`.
after checking it closely the server variables are like this :

```
  SERVER_NAME => localhost
  HTTP_HOST => localhost
  HOST => local.io
```

I've been playing with :

```
    1. open phpunit.xml file, add <server name="host" value="local.io"/> and <server name="http_host" value="local.io"/>
    2. open TestCase.php, add URL::forceRootUrl('http://local.io'); in the setUp() function
    3. I even change the server headers in the $this->call() function
```

But it always redirecting me to `http://local.io/en`

Hopefully someone can give me a clue on what's happening.

Comment: Where's your code that handles the en prefix?

Comment: I think `App::setLocale('en');` handles the `en` prefix, because if I use `/en/user/signin`, it always returns `NotFoundExceptiion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, and I'm sharing it here, hopefully it helps other people having the same problem.

the issue was caused by the mcamara localization package, for every request to server, server will redirect to the `localized URL`, client browser will then send another request along with the `locale` value, say `en`, so it will be a double request for every request.

I decided to write a new helper class, and then attach it to the route files (admin and user), it will check if the environment is `testing`, it will return only 1 filter, otherwise it will return 2 filters.

For a complete answer and solution, please follow this article :
https://www.munderwood.ca/index.php/2016/03/16/testing-routes-with-laravel-localization/#comment-1562

this issue happens only in Laravel 4.2, as for version 5 and above, mcamara already provides a workaround, just visit their github page and scroll to bottom